# How to make angular material dialog box work in IE10

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I want to use angular material dialog box but in IE10 it don't show white background. There is only text on grayed background. When I inspect the md-dialog element and see css the background-color is applied but background is not visible.

Anybody know how to fix this issue in IE. The same happen on [demo page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
md-dialog {
    float: left;
}
```

fixed the issue

Comment: AFAIK Dialog box don't use flex